# Jquery-styled dropdownlist no longer posts back / fires onselectedindexchanged event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

ASP.Net 3.5 through C# in Visual Studio 2008.

Simple enough problem i think but I can't find a solution to it online. I've a dropdownlist that was successfully posting back using the autopostback. I styled it using this jquery styler:
[Selectbox Style](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)

and since then it no longer posts back. This appears to be because Jquery is altering the code to facilitate the styling, which is fine, I just need to find a way to trigger the selectedindexchange event, or make jquery update the select box when someone changes the selection in the styled 'version' of the dropdownlist.

Any ideas?

This is the code Jquery produces:

```
<div class="test" sb="14935647" style="display: none;">
<select id="ctl00_Body_ucSets_rptSelections_ctl00_ddlAttributeSelection" class="dropdown" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$Body$ucSets$rptSelections$ctl00$ddlAttributeSelection\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$Body$ucSets$rptSelections$ctl00$ddlAttributeSelection">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Change Colour</option>
<option value="14">Red</option>
<option value="21">Black</option>
<option value="22">Pink</option>
<option value="23">Green</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="sbHolder_14935647" class="sbHolder">
</div>
```

While this is what my actual C# code is:

```
<div class="test">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAttributeSelection" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown"
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAttributeSelection_selectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the code you have right now?

Comment: add your code to the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not post back because what you are seeing on screen is not your DropDownList. If you inspect your DOM you will see that the jQuery has turned your DropDownList into an unordered list ( `<ul>` ) with many list elements ( `<li>` )

**Edit**

From looking at the jQuery, there is an event which you can use `onchange` which you will need to use to then call your `OnSelectedIndexChanged` through javascript

Comment: This is what I suspected alright. Does anyone know of a way to style a dropdownlist that keeps the autopostback functionality?

Comment: There is no way to style up a dropdown list in this way and keep the autopostback functionality. It will require some javascript to do the postback

Comment: I'd spotted that onChange event but am at a loss how to get the OnSelectedIndexChanged to know the value selected as it's not actually being changed by the user, if you follow me.

Comment: What you will need to do is use the onChange even to populate a hiddenfield with the value, then have a button on the page which you can do a postback with. In the code behind you can then use the value of the hidden field.